# complicated fetch from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have created 2 tables with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscr_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)


CREATE TABLE `payments_data` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subscr_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txn_type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscr_date` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period3` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount3` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

In production environment, I will be given an email (stored in users table) and than fetch `subscr_id` for that `email`. Then I will need to get `txn_type` for user whose `payments_data.subscr_id=users.subscr_id`

Basically I am trying to get `txn_type` for specfic `email`. I tried solving this with JOINs, but my understanding was to shallow.. any idea how to create this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query with JOIN and WHERE to filter out the email adress should be something like this.

```
   SELECT 
      payments_data.txn_type
    FROM 
      users 
    INNER JOIN 
      payments_data
    ON
      users.subscr_id = payments_data.subscr_id
    WHERE
      users.email = 'example@hotmail.com'
```

Comment: @brumbrum if this answer helped you please mark the answer as solved